# MVVMCross Android Emulator fails to launch

Tags: android, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm not 100% sure that MVVMCross is the culprit but I've successfully launched the Android emulator while debugging a default Android app but cannot do the same with a fairly simple cross platform app.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 (Update 4) on Windows 8.1 and using the MVVMCross tutorial added a PCL ViewModel and then a Windows Store app which I am able to run successfully.

I then created an Android app using the same PCL and simple view but whenever I go to Debug the app I get a Device Unavailable dialog stating

"Device: No Devices Attached is either not running or not attached.

Available devices:
Motorola Xoom"

Available devices may also show a running emulator instance.

Again, I don't see the same issue with a default Android app.

Update:
Tried deleting the .suo file but no help there
A default android app in the same solution will not launch the emulator either

Comment: Have you set the app as the startup project?

Comment: lol - what a dolt.  me that is.  I was just trying o debug the project with the core library as the default project which I could do with the store app.  thanks